# Error when clicking on ListView, D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-adapter

Hello I am trying to learn Android development and I am building a new application. I have implemented a ListFragment and an adapter to display some notes. The notes are displayed as I wanted but now when I click on an item I cannot fire another activity and I see the error above in the Log. My code is shown below.

This is the main Fragment

```
 public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<NoteStructure> notes;
private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;
public MainListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     notes = new ArrayList<NoteStructure>();
    notes.add(new NoteStructure("malakia", "sdfsfsdfffffffsdfsfsfdfsfsds"));
    notes.add(new NoteStructure("sou gamw", "gamithikessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"));
    noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(getActivity(),notes);
    setListAdapter(noteAdapter);
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id){

    super.onListItemClick(listView,view,position,id);
    Log.e("Item" ,"click"+ position);
    procceedToOtherActivity(position);
}
private void procceedToOtherActivity (int position){

    NoteStructure note = (NoteStructure) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTEID,note.getNoteId() );
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTETITLE,note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTESUMMARY,note.getSummary());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Here is the Note adapter:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoteStructure> {

public static class ViewRef {

    TextView noteTitle;
    TextView noteSummary;
}
public NoteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NoteStructure> notes){

    super(context,0,notes);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    NoteStructure note = getItem(position);
    ViewRef viewRef;
    if(convertView==null) {

        viewRef = new ViewRef();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row,parent,false);
        viewRef.noteTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteTitle);
        viewRef.noteSummary=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteSummary);
        convertView.setTag(viewRef);
    }
    else {

        viewRef = (ViewRef) convertView.getTag();
    }



    viewRef.noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
    viewRef.noteSummary.setText(note.getSummary());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I have also a NoteStructure class that just holds id, title and summary variables along with getters and setters, and the the mainActivity and DetailActivity dont do anything for now. I have searched a lot but I couldn't figure out the problem why the DetaiLActivity doesn't fire up. Can someone please help me?

Here is my implementention with an ad hoc listener

```
public class MainListFragment extends Fragment {

private View view;
private ListView list;
private ArrayList<NoteStructure> notes;
private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;
public MainListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_layout, container, false);

    list= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
     notes = new ArrayList<NoteStructure>();
    notes.add(new NoteStructure("malakia", "sdfsfsdfffffffsdfsfsfdfsfsds"));
    notes.add(new NoteStructure("sou gamw", "gamithikessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"));

    noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(getActivity(),notes);
    list.setAdapter(noteAdapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            procceedToOtherActivity(position);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void procceedToOtherActivity (int position){

    NoteStructure note = (NoteStructure) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTEID,note.getNoteId() );
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTETITLE,note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTESUMMARY,note.getSummary());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: `Log.e("Item" ,"click"+ position);` - Do you see this line in the logs and if you do is it correct?

Comment: No I dont see it. I see only D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Answer (score 1):

Your itemClickListener is not firing. You should either override listener like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO implement some logic
}
```

or you should extend normal fragment

```
public class MainListFragment extends Fragment{
```

and make ad hoc simple listener for listview:

```
listview.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            procceedToOtherActivity(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did it with an ad hoc listener but still the same result. You can see my implementantion above...

Comment: Put `Log.e("Item" ,"click"+ position);` in the setOnItemClickListener and in the procceedToOtherActivity and then see do you even get the event

Comment: I found the solution. Both implementantions work. the problem is that I want to show each row of the list view to have a title and a summary. so in my custom layout I had two text views inside a Linear layout and I have to put android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the linear layout so that the text views do not absorb the clicks

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution at last and if I contributed to that!

Comment: No problem. You could mark my answer as correct. thanks